# What is the fastest way to take dump of a table in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I'm trying to take a dump of a table on to remote disk mounted on my server and below is the cmd I've used.
Exporting of dump started and after 6 hours below ORA errors where thrown.
Looking for a better way:

```
ORA-02354: error in exporting/importing data
ORA-01555: snapshot too old: rollback segment number 17 with name "_SYSSMU17$" too small
```

Command used:

```
expdp user/password TABLES=TABLE_NAME DIRECTORY=TEST_DIR DUMPFILE=DUMP.dmp LOGFILE=LOG.log
```

Comment: Is this a big table?

Comment: This sounds like a combination of slow access to the remote disk, volume of the data, and the updates happening to the source table is ultimately having issues with read consistency.  I suggest exporting to faster disk, local disk if possible, and trying to export only data that is not changing, like copying the data in the database to a staging table before export.